# QGIS not saving layer in Lo 19 / EPSG:2048

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile

I am reprojecting a shapefile from lat/long to [Hartebeeshoek Lo19](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/hartebeesthoek94-lo19/) using 'set layer crs', however when saving the shapefile ('export as') the output remains in lat/long?

Set CRS:

[image: example1]

Save the reprojected shapefile:

[image: example2]

Comment: You **do not set** a layers CRS, you either transform the layer using the tool with the same name, or export the layer to a new file, choosing a different CRS. Also please specify what you mean by "the output remains in lat/long", maybe attach a screenshot of your data.

Comment: Please check some tutorials about `"reprojecting in QGIS"` e.g. [Working with Projections](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_projections.html) or [7.1. Lesson: Reprojecting and Transforming Data](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the CRS first. Keep it in WGS84.

You set the CRS when you are in the "Save layer as..." dialog.

If you set it first, QGIS assumes it is already in LO19, so doesn't reproject it.